# How to request specific data from WMS layers on OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, cql, geoserver

Im new on Openlayers/Geoserver and im trying to add a panel where i can change settings like "Price" , "Area size" ... and display only the data which comply with the information given in my HTML page.

I can already do this with : 'cql_filter': 'sterr<(value)' in my TileWMS params but i dont know how to change it manually on my html page.

I'm also wondering if this is the good way to achieve what im trying to ?

[EDIT] 
I added some screenshot of my code , index.js where i want to be able to change the cql_filter params [index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBHdd.png)

Here is my index.html with a form [index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtthS.png)

What i want at the end, a panel where the user could change the value and get all the specific data ( here we have apartments between 50m² and 200m² )[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3yA7.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this,

index.html - change form with this, just to make it simple

```
Min:<br>
<input id="rmin" type="number" value="50">
<br>
Max:<br>
<input id="rmax" type="number" value="200">
<br><br>
<button onclick="update()">Update Layer</button>
```

index.js - add the update function

```
var update = function() {
  var rmin = Number(document.getElementById('rmin').value);
  var rmax = Number(document.getElementById('rmax').value);
  mutnimesSource.updateParams({
    'LAYERS': 'ocimutnimes',
    'TILED': true,
    'cql_filter': `sterr BETWEEN ${rmin} AND ${rmax}`
  });
  console.log(rmin + ' - ' + rmax);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal, but when i do as u said i have the following error : Uncaught ReferenceError : update is not defined. 
I added the following line : var update = new update(); but i cant use the button because this will give me back the Uncaught ReferenceError

Comment: You need to add the function to the code, all the code. The button invokes the function when is clicked. Maybe you are confuse, you are defining the function update, and is a function you don't need to do new. Try again and let me know.

Comment: I added the function at the end of my index.js but when i press the button to invoke the function i have an error from the console saying "Uncaught ReferenceError : update is not defined". calling function from my index.html don't work but i have no clue why.

Comment: Did you replace the html form part with the code that I give you?.

Comment: Yeah it's the same, calling the function inside index.js work fine but not inside index.html

Comment: Lets try to add to attach the event on javascript. To do this, 1) in the html change the button line to this `<button id="btnUpdate">Update Layer</button>`, 2) in the javascript add the line `document.getElementById('btnUpdate').addEventListener('click', update());`

Comment: The page should not refresh, it just a button click. Can you add the updated code to the post, I need to see how you have it now to help you.

Comment: I found a solution thanks to your help cabesuon and this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53760715/changing-global-variable-by-user-input-via-function/53762776#53762776
And for the refresh my button was in a <form>